# MySQL query that counts and also checks for match?

Tags: mysql

I have this queries that counts all rows taht match Site = $site:

```
$count= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `Site`) FROM `Ratings` WHERE `Site` = '$site'");
```

The query above gets the number of ratings for a $site. But I also need to know if the user already rated the site. I'm using use another COUNT for this:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Ratings` WHERE `Site` = '$site' AND `UID` = '$uid'"
```

Is it possible to get the number of site matches and check if the user rated the site in one query? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it isn't very straightforward but you can do this in one query. Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'num_ratings', IF(`UID` = '$uid','YES','NO') as 'already_rated' FROM `Ratings` WHERE `Site` = '$site' ORDER BY already_rated DESC
```

This query will return you 1 row with 2 columns. The first column `num_ratings` will be the number of ratings for that particular site, and the `already_rated` will tell you if that particular user has rated the site. (It will be either 'YES' or 'NO')

The `ORDER BY already_rated DESC` insures that if the user has rated the site, it will return YES, because YES comes after NO in the alphabet. This is necessary because when you use `COUNT()` the rows are being grouped together.

**EDIT: After further testing, the solution above WILL NOT WORK. Use this one instead.**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'num_ratings' IF(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`UID` = '$uid', 'YES','NO') SEPARATOR ',') LIKE '%yes%', 'YES','NO') as 'already_rated' FROM `Ratings` WHERE `Site` = '$site'
```

Comment: If it is indeed possible in MySQL to group "on the fly" by values in the select list, as you are suggesting in this case with the Yes/No column, then your query will return 2 rows, and the count will be off by 1 if the user rated. If it is not possible to do this, it will produce an error. How can you possibly combine an aggregate function with an evaluation of individual rows in one query?

Comment: @cdonner If you leave out the GROUP BY clause, it's equivalent to grouping by all rows. (pulled straight from this [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).
I tested my query in mysql on one of my own tables, and it returns one row with two columns as I have stated above.

Comment: @cdonner7 I am just adding something to the SELECT clause, so it will not affect the count at all.

Comment: @cdonner7 I guess there are some big differences between sql and mysql... I learned that quickly when my answers for sql questions kept getting down-votes because I provided a mysql solution... haha

Comment: I had to test this myself. Your query returns 'YES' only if the user in question happens to be the first row in the result set. Apparently the IF condition is applied to the first row only.

Comment: @cdonner That's why I included the ORDER BY clause so if the user exists in the result set, that row will be first. Are you saying that the ORDER BY clause isn't actually doing this?

Comment: yes, I included your ORDER BY and it did not change the result (how should it, if there is only one row?)

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense (but is also no longer as elegant) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have only superficial knowledge of MySQL and I have seen that it does certain things differently than other DBMSs (sometimes better), but I still think that you are not counting ratings per site with your query, but rather the number of 'distinct' sites in your Ratings table, which is always 1 if constrained with a Site parameter.
You need a GROUP BY in order to count ratings by site, as in:

```
SELECT
  count(*)
FROM `Ratings`
WHERE `Site` = '$site' 
GROUP BY `Site`
```

You have different options for including a check if the user rated a site. One is a correlated subquery, which gives you the information for each site in the result set.

```
SELECT
  count(*),
  (SELECT count(*) from `Ratings` where `Site` = r.`Site` and `UID` = '$uid') 
         as has_rated
FROM `Ratings` r
WHERE `Site` = '$site' 
GROUP BY `Site`
```

Another would be a self-join - something that usually has a performance advantage over a subquery (the subquery has to be evaluated for each row in the result set and the join does not). But since you are constraining your query by site and always expecting only one row in the result set, it would make very little difference.